# Import one-dimensional string to two-dimensional int array

Tags: java, arrays, import, int, sudoku

I want to import Sudoku boards and convert them to a [9][9] array.

[Example of a couple of printed boards:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Lrb.png)

Here is the first board:
370000001000700005408061090000010000050090460086002030000000000694005203800149500

The first 9 numbers fill the first row, the next 9 number fill the second row etc.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    File in = new File("board.txt");
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                grid[i][j]= input.nextInt();
            }

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }
```

This code can import individual ints in a text file for example:

```
0
1
3
5
0
8
etc
```

So how do I either edit the code I have so it can "read" a line of numbers without spaces and import every individual digit from the text file in an element.

Or how do I create a new program that fills the same function?

Answer (score 1):

Use `scanner.nextLine` read the line and use `Integer.parseInt` convert `char` to `int`:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
    String line = input.nextLine();   
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            grid[i][j]= Integer.parseInt(line.charAt(i * 9 + j));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you can read all the line, then you can follow this steps :

```
int[][] result = Arrays.asList(line.split("(?<=\\G.{9})"))//cut in each 9 element
        .stream()
        .map(row -> Stream.of(row.split(""))//Split each row
                        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()//convert it to array of ints
        ).toArray(int[][]::new);//Collect the result as a int[][]

Arrays.asList(result).forEach(row -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row)));//Print
```

**Outputs**

```
[3, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
[4, 0, 8, 0, 6, 1, 0, 9, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 4, 6, 0]
[0, 8, 6, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[6, 9, 4, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 3]
[8, 0, 0, 1, 4, 9, 5, 0, 0]
```